# Prolog - distance from two point

Tags: prolog, position, distance

i want calculate distance from two cites, i have cityState, list of lists of

```
[NameCity,[X,Y],Neighbours],[],..]
```

I'm trying to write a code in Prolog to calculate the distanze beetween two cities, but when i tried to execute the predicate 'distance', obtain

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: distance
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR:  (a,b,Distance) .
```

My implementation:

```
cityState([[a,[2,3],[b,d]],[b,[5,1],[a,c,d]], [c, [3, 2], [b, d]], [d, [6, 3], [a, b, c]]]).

city(Name,Position,Neighbors):-
cityState(L),
member([Name,Position,Neighbors],L),
!.
position(Name,Position):-
city(Name,Position,_Neighbors).

distance(City1,City2,Distance):-
position(City1,[X1,Y1]),
position(City2,[X2,Y2]),
X_Dist is (X1-X2) ** 2,
Y_Dist is (Y1-Y2) ** 2,
Distance is sqrt(X_Dist + Y_Dist).
```

I expect the output of Distance is ..how i can do ?

Comment: Did you add a space between the predicate and the brackets?

Comment: You should write `distance(a, b, Distance), *not* `distance (a, b, Distance)`. Yeah, I know that is annoying.